# see the results of HTML in Python

Tags: javascript, python, html

I have to make control buttons in HTML, so when someone click on the buttons the result should be print function in Python with words: "Button is pressed".
Here is the basic HTML code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="white">  
    <form>
        <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.cz', 'This is Google')">
        <input type="button" value="Color" onclick="document.bgColor='red'">
        <input type="button" value="Color_back" onclick="document.bgColor='white'">
    </form>
</body>
```

I tried to search some related example of python code for interaction with HTML but this is everything I found and I really need some help. So help me please:

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

class MyRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            self.path = '/Programming for WEB/Robotic_hand_control.html'
        return SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)

Handler = MyRequestHandler
server = SocketServer.TCPServer(('localhost', 8080), Handler)

server.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

1) Another handler in the python code that will accept requests

2) Revise the onclick to send data to the handler

3) in the handler code print the data that was sent

Check this out: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BaseHttpServer

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand how to revise the onclick to send data to the handler and how to print the data that was sent. I tried something like this above.